# Creating rule to create time based on delivery rate

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have a condition on my form that calculates the delivery time of the orders, follows the rule below:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$Agora = date('H:i:s');
$HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+69 minute', strtotime($Agora)));

if ( $entrega == '5.00'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+120 minute', strtotime($Agora)));
}

if ( $entrega == '3.80'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+30 minute', strtotime($Agora)));

}

else if  ( $entrega == '7.0'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+20 minute', strtotime($Agora)));

};
```

What I need is to create a rule where $HoraServico is based on the delivery value $entrega

Example: If the delivery fee costs $ 7.00 then the delivery time will be the sum of the current time ($Agora) + 120 minutes.

If the delivery fee costs $ 2.00 then the delivery time will be the sum of the current time ($Agora) + 30 minutes. And so on.

The idea is, the more expensive the delivery rate (because it is far) the more time it will cost to deliver.

I tested like this, but it's not going! He is adding only the line:

`$HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+69 minute', strtotime($Agora)));`

That is, always adding 69 minutes

As I understand it, he is not computing correctly the delivery rate that actually takes information from this line:

`$entrega = $_POST["taxadeentrega"];`

Sorry for the English, I'm Brazilian and I'm using a translator, in the community in Portuguese, nobody has answer!...

Just for the knowledge of you, it follows part of the code that calculates the value of the freight, this excerpt is in a JS file.

```
    }if(cep == "20010-020" || cep == "20011-020" || cep == "20011-030" || cep == "20011-040" || cep == "20011-901" || cep == "20020-000" || cep == "20010-170" || cep == "20011-000" || cep == "20021-260" || cep == "20031-040" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-130" || cep == "20031-204" || cep == "20021-245" || cep == "20040-002" || cep == "21335-253" || cep == "20040-031" || cep == "20030-041" || cep == "20040-000" || cep == "20004-002" || cep == "20040-003" || cep == "20040-007" || cep == "20030-042" || cep == "20011-010"){

        //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.7 no valor final
        taxa = 2.00;


    }if(cep == "20010-090" || cep == "20020-100" || cep == "20021-130" || cep == "20021-315" || cep == "20030-001" || cep == "20031-000" || cep == "20031-003" || cep == "20031-010" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-141" || cep == "20031-143" || cep == "20031-005" || cep == "20031-001" || cep == "20020-903" || cep == "20031-144" || cep == "20030-080" || cep == "20031-142" || cep == "20031-120" || cep == "20031-007" || cep == "20010-009" || cep == "20031-913" || cep == "20021-370" || cep == "20200-100" || cep == "20030-901" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20210-030" || cep == "24220-280"){

        //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.2 no valor final
        taxa = 1.50;


    }if(cep == "20020-010"|| cep == "22050-032" || cep == "20020-040" || cep == "20020-080" || cep == "20021-060" || cep == "20021-120" || cep == "20021-900" || cep == "20021-903" || cep == "20030-002" || cep == "20030-015" || cep == "20030-013" || cep == "20030-020" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20030-060" || cep == "20030-070" || cep == "20030-120" || cep == "20002-080" || cep == "20002-008" || cep == "20003-021" || cep == "20030-905" || cep == "24220-031" || cep == "20002-010" || cep == "20030-015"){

        //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 0.7 no valor final
        taxa = 1.00; 

    }

total += taxa;      

if(taxa != 0){

//caso a taxa seja diferente de 0, mostra ao usuário
    document.getElementById("idTaxa").innerHTML = "Additional charge R$ " + taxa;
}
```

Comment: Four things to start with: 1. Why do you store amounts of money in strings? 2. You should never check whether two floating points are exactly equal, they rarely are. 3. You compare two values with `==` because `=` is an assignment. 4. One `else` seems to be missing.

Comment: I have in this form a function, where for each CEP has a value to be charged, what I want now is based on this value, be added a time.
I am a layman, in the Portuguese community I have been given this code, which is not working, if you can help me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple but common mistake in the code:

```
if ( $entrega = '5.00') {
```

This is not correct.  This is making an assignment of the value of 5.00 rather than checking for equality.

This should be:

```
    if ( $entrega == '5.00') {
```

The same mistake was made with all the comparisons.

This code is also not DRY.  The same line of code is repeated over and over:

```
 $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+30 minute', strtotime($Agora)));
```

It would be better if the time increment (ie.  '+30 minute') was a variable that was set in the if-then-else, or better yet in a switch statement, since these are all mutually exclusive.

```
switch ($entraga) {
    case '5.00':
        $mins = '+120 minute';
        break;
    case '2.00':
        $mins = '+30 minute';
        break;
    case '7.00':
        $mins = '+20 minute';
        break;

    default:
        $mins = '+69 minute'
}
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$Agora = date('H:i:s');
$HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime($mins, strtotime($Agora)));
```

Comment: I put it as you explained, but even so he does not recognize the rule. It is only adding, always, with 69 minutes. From what I'm noticing he is not reading correctly the rule that refers to delivery rate ($entrega)

Comment: Your code only works if $entraga is being set correctly.  That code is not included, but you should debug that by echoing out the value of $entraga and checking it..  With that said, the code could not possibly have worked correctly given the mistake in making assignment vs. logical comparison.

Comment: Thanks for listening! It still continues to add up to only 69 minutes, I do not know why, but it is not recognizing the rule.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to rewrite this code it would be something like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

function deliveryTime($shippingCost)
{
  $delay = 69; // minutes of delay in the delivery
  if ($shippingCost >= 2.00) $delay += 30; // added minutes when shipping is over 2
  if ($shippingCost >= 5.00) $delay += 30; // added minutes when shipping is over 5
  if ($shippingCost >= 7.00) $delay += 30; // added minutes when shipping is over 7
  return date('H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$delay.' minute'));
}

$horaServico = deliveryTime($entraga);
```

Comment: Thanks for listening! It still continues to add up to only 69 minutes, I do not know why, but it is not recognizing the rule.

Comment: Time to check the variables. You can do this by placing `echo <variable>` in strategic places. I would like to know the content of `$entraga`.

Comment: This delivery rate ($ delivery) is loaded through this code:

`$entrega = $_POST["taxadeentrega"];`

In the file form.js has a function that calculates the value of the taxe of delivery through the CEP and shows this in the form across the field taxadeentrega.

Comment: If there really is an $ sign in `$entraga` then it is not a number and cannot be used in a numerical comparison. We would have to remove the $ sign first.

Comment: No, it does not have the $ symbol it's just number